# Laravel Query Builder get sum with clause and results

Tags: json, laravel, sum

I have this table :

```
created_at | name | source
```

this is my builder query:

```php
$data = Contact::select(
    DB::raw('DATE_FORMAT(created_at, "%m-%d-%Y")'),
    DB::raw('SUM(source = "IG") as instagram'),
    DB::raw('SUM(source = "FBS") as facebook')
)
->orderBy('data', 'DESC')
->groupBy(DB::raw("DATE_FORMAT(created_at, '%d-%m-%Y')"))
->get();

return response()->json(['contacts' => $data], 200);
```

I get a correct Json with sum, groupBy and ordered by data:

```json
{
    "contacts": [
        {
            "created_at": "01-17-2022",
            "www": "0",
            "FBS": "42"
        },
        {
            "created_at": "01-16-2022",
            "www": "3",
            "FBS": "68"
        }
    ]
}
```

But in this way I would be forced to make another json to explode all the data, instead I'd like to return results with details for each rows, like this:

```json
{
    "contacts": [
        {
            "created_at": "01-17-2022",
            "www": [
                { 
                    counts : 0
                }
            ],
            "FBS": [
                { 
                    counts : 42
                }, 
                { 
                    name : "John Doe",
                    source: "FBS"   
                },
                ...
            ]
        },
        {
            "created_at": "01-16-2022",
            "www": [
                { 
                    counts : 3
                },
                { 
                    name : "John Doe",
                    source: "FBS"   
                }, 
                { 
                    name : "Jane Doe",
                    source: "FBS"   
                }, 
                ...
            ],
            "FBS": [
                { 
                    counts : 68,
                }, 
                { 
                    name : "John Doe",
                    source: "FBS"   
                }, 
                { 
                    name : "Jane Doe",
                    source: "FBS"   
                }, 
                ...
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Should I completely change my query? What is the best way for get it?

Comment: Your output expectation is invalid. Better validate first.

Comment: @Wahyu Kristianto  sorry, validated now.